# Copying text from browser with line breaks in Android

Tags: android, browser, newline, copy-paste, line-breaks

In my app, a user has to copy required text from browser and paste it to the textview.
But copy'n'pasting this way removes most of line breaks. How do I fix it?

Comment: use \n where line breaks

Comment: ok, how to do it? when user copies text, in buffer it's already corrupted so i can't do anything

Comment: then you have to its read its html and then replace <br> tag with \n

Comment: so i should analyse the text that user copied, then parse HTML source, find required text fragment there and copy it with replaced <br>. seems too difficult for such problem, may be there's an easier solution?

Comment: I think you are lazy. this is the solution try it

Comment: well, you're right) but what if there're some HTML-tags (not only <br>) in HTML-code which is displaying the required text? it makes your solution much harder

Comment: http://www.techsupportalert.com/remove-unwanted-formatting-from-text.htm  here's the same problem, but i want to solve it programaticaly not with another apps

Comment: one more solution :: you can create webview instead of textview and paste there html code

Comment: so are there any other solutions?

Comment: To anyone wondering decade later, changing browser or trying other text editor helps. For my case copying github raw from Samsung Internet didn't work, but copying from chrome works, and same for txt file in google drive vs download and open in QuickEdit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to enforce browser usage, I find that Chrome on Android preserves line breaks when copying and pasting much better than Firefox. I recently ran into this issue when copying source code from an HTML page that did not have `<br />`'s (as when text is formatted with `<pre>`).  Copying from Firefox consistently ignored line breaks, but Chrome copied them without issue.